# How to order by rows, then columns, in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I created a temp table with all the data I want. I'm then pulling the data using a dynamic pivot and trying to figure out how to sort by rows, then pivoted columns. I have the row sort but can't figure out how to sort on the pivoted columns.

```
SET @COLS = N'';
SET @COLS2 = N'';

SELECT @COLS += N', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName), @COLS2 += N', ' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName)
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT(PivotedName) FROM #TEMP1 T1) AS X;

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT [ID#],[Name],' + STUFF( @COLS, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM        
(
    SELECT T1.[ID#], T1.[Name], T1.PivotedName, T1.PivotedAggregate FROM #TEMP1 T1 

) AS C
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(PivotedAggregate) FOR PivotedName IN (' + STUFF(REPLACE(@COLS2, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')
) AS P

ORDER BY [ID#] DESC
;';


EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

Results return like this, where they are sorted by ID# DESC, which I want. But secondarily, I would like them sorted by "PivotName" but not Alphabetically, actually by another column "SortOrder", which is available in #TEMP1.

Actual results:

```
ID# Name    PivotName1  PivotName4  PivotName3  PivotName2
10  Jon     10          0.91            9           0.91
9   Jane    8           15.8            14          0.8
8   Tom     6           0.84            6           0.84
7   Steve   3.37        0.85            37.5        0.99
6   Bob     0.75        0.73            0.75        0.73
```

Desired results:

```
ID# Name    PivotName1  PivotName2  PivotName3  PivotName4
10  Jon     10          0.91        9           0.91
9   Jane    8           0.8         14          15.8
```

Comment: Seems like you just need to add an `ORDER BY` to your `SELECT @COLS`.... statement

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example? Everything I've tried errors out. I read some recommendations that it would have to incorporate XML of which I know very little.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, you need to add an `ORDER BY`. Just change:

```
SELECT @COLS += N', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName), @COLS2 += N', ' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName)
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT(PivotedName) FROM #TEMP1 T1) AS X;
```

To

```
SELECT @COLS += N', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName), @COLS2 += N', ' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName)
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT(PivotedName) FROM #TEMP1 T1) AS X ORDER BY PivotedName;
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I can see that I was not clear enough. I don't want to order by PivotedName, I want to order by a different field in #TEMP1 that I do not actually need to return in my data.

Comment: You can't order your data by a column that doesn't exist in the dataset @userKW .

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT @COLS += N', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName), @COLS2 += N', ' + QUOTENAME(PivotedName)
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT(PivotedName), SortOrder FROM #TEMP1 T1) AS X ORDER BY SortOrder;
```

Got it figured out. I pulled the sortorder from the temp table for sorting but didn't use it in my final sql. Thanks for the discussion.